# photoshop foreground color of image cant be changed

Tags: photoshop, element

I clicked on the foreground/background little square tool icons, selected the color I want and clicked ok. The small tool icon is showing the new color but the image itself hasn't changed the color. And yes confirmed that the mode is RGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a tool to apply the color as needed...

Did you use the paint bucket or brush to actually add the new color to the image?
Simply changing the color of this box does not change the foreground background color automatically